# Go delve debugger "Command failed: Access is denied." when setting breakpoint

Tags: go, delve

I'm using the latest Go on Windows (v1.18) and the latest Delve (v1.8.2) and when I run `dlv debug` from the command prompt, and then try to add any breakpoint (`b main:1`) , it displays `Command failed: Access is denied.` I've confirmed the folder and source files are writeable, and I've also run `dlv` from an Administrator command prompt with the same result.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

FYI for others searching, turns out that "dlv.exe" was being blocked by my antivirus software.